# localhost:3000 is not rendering the node tutorial

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mean-stack

I'm currently going through the thinkster MEAN tutorial - and really just starting to learn the stack.  I was busy building in the day, and all worked fine. The moment I got home, I couldn't run anything. As use npm start, I am able to use curl GET commands to get documents through the API layer, the build itself doesn't render and I get a 404. See below:

```
> Not Found 404 Error: Not Found at
> C:\Users\user\Documents\Stuff\misc\AngularTutorial\MEAN-Chapterized\flapper-news\app.js:37:13
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request]
> (C:\Users\user\Documents\Stuff\misc\AngularTutorial\MEAN-Chapterized\flapper-news\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
> at trim_prefix
> (C:\Users\user\Documents\Stuff\misc\AngularTutorial\MEAN-Chapterized\flapper-news\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:312:13)
> at
> C:\Users\user\Documents\Stuff\misc\AngularTutorial\MEAN-Chapterized\flapper-news\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:7
> at Function.process_params
> (C:\Users\user\Documents\Stuff\misc\AngularTutorial\MEAN-Chapterized\flapper-news\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:330:12)
> at next
> (C:\Users\user\Documents\Stuff\misc\AngularTutorial\MEAN-Chapterized\flapper-news\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:271:10)
> at
> C:\Users\user\Documents\Stuff\misc\AngularTutorial\MEAN-Chapterized\flapper-news\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:618:15
> at next
> (C:\Users\user\Documents\Stuff\misc\AngularTutorial\MEAN-Chapterized\flapper-news\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:256:14)
> at Function.handle
> (C:\Users\user\Documents\Stuff\misc\AngularTutorial\MEAN-Chapterized\flapper-news\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:176:3)
> at router
> (C:\Users\user\Documents\Stuff\misc\AngularTutorial\MEAN-Chapterized\flapper-news\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:46:12)
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request]
> (C:\Users\user\Documents\Stuff\misc\AngularTutorial\MEAN-Chapterized\flapper-news\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
> at trim_prefix
> (C:\Users\user\Documents\Stuff\misc\AngularTutorial\MEAN-Chapterized\flapper-news\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:312:13)
> at
> C:\Users\user\Documents\Stuff\misc\AngularTutorial\MEAN-Chapterized\flapper-news\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:7
> at Function.process_params
> (C:\Users\user\Documents\Stuff\misc\AngularTutorial\MEAN-Chapterized\flapper-news\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:330:12)
> at next
> (C:\Users\user\Documents\Stuff\misc\AngularTutorial\MEAN-Chapterized\flapper-news\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:271:10)
> at SendStream.error
> (C:\Users\user\Documents\Stuff\misc\AngularTutorial\MEAN-Chapterized\flapper-news\node_modules\serve-static\index.js:121:7)
```

The git repo with the most recent build is here:https://github.com/Rainer88/MEAN-Chapterized.git

If you could point me in the right direction, that would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us the URL you're accessing? is it accessible from postman?

Comment: @Sridhar I'm using localhost:3000... it returns the raw format of my mongo collections when using localhost:3000/posts but nothing more.

Comment: I ran your code, things seem to be working good. Can you add a little more context to the question in terms of what URL you're hitting, what you are getting and what is expected.

Comment: @Sridhar This is the snippet from postman? Not too sure what I'm looking for though?
GET /home HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3000
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 7be6bbb4-8a49-4bc6-ba5e-82f777b780ed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> GET /home

**Why 404?**

Your `index.js` on routes folder doesn't have any configurations for `GET` on `/home`. Hence you are getting a `404`. Similarly, you have no routes configured for `GET` on `/` too.

> GET /

You'll get a `404` for that as well. So, you need to configure routes for those endpoints

```
router.get('/home', function (req, res) {
    res.send({
        msg: 'hello world from /home'
    });
});

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send({
        msg: 'hello world from at /'
    });
});
```

Comment: faceplam... Thank you!  that slipped through the cracks on my side